# How to force QWidget to be shown in a separate window?

Tags: qt4, qwidget

I have

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWidget (QWidget *parent);
    // ...
};

// here is ALL the code in MyWidget constructor
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    glWidget = new GLWidget(this, cluster);

    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(glWidget);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setWindowTitle("Visualization");
}
```

and the main window `MainWindow w;`.

I want

1. to create new instances of MyWidget from `w`;
2. that instances to be destroyed after `QCloseEvent` or with `w` (now they are destroyed only after `QCloseEvent`);
3. that instances to appear in new windows.

I am creating new instance of `MyWidget` like this:

```
void MainWindow::visualize()
{
    MyWidget *widg = new MyWidget(this); // or widg = new MyWidget(0)
    widg->show();
    widg->raise();
    widg->activateWindow();
}
```

When I try to create `widg` with `w` as a `parent`, `widg` appears inside of the `w` (in left top corner).

What is the easiest and most clear way to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent, Qt::Window)
{
    glWidget = new GLWidget(this, cluster);

    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(glWidget);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setWindowTitle("Visualization");
}
```

Adding [`Qt::Window`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) to the constructor of [`QWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html) should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As it is written in [QWidget's constructor reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#QWidget) for a widget to become a window its parent should be 0. But when the parent is 0 it mens the parent is "YOU" :) - i.e you have to look after them - keep them to some reachable place and destroy them when the time is appropriate (either on close event, destructor or using shared pointers).

Comment: What about Qt::Window as WindowFlags? That does not require you to run without a parent.

Comment: @something: you're right, I forgot about the flags. Thanks for the recall.